# Need help compiling with g++ if the code have threading functionalities using std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, mingw

my code is very simple all I want is to print the number of cores of my PC
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    unsigned int nCores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << "This machine supports concurrency with " << nCores << " cores available" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have MinGW: gcc (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0
and I compile the code using `g++ -std=c++17 .\concurr1.cpp` but
this error appears

```
.\concurr1.cpp:6:32: error: 'std::thread' has not been declared
     unsigned int nCores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

Comment: Also, if you rely on a specific language version, check for it (`#if __cplusplus < 201703L` --  `#error Needs to be compiled in C++17 mode` -- `#endif`). That would give you (and us) the confidence that the compiler is indeed running in the correct mode.

Comment: With the given snippet, C++17 is not required though.

Comment: Did you link the threading library for your platform?

Comment: With the given snippet, I cannot reproduce this with MinGW GCC 9.2.0 either way; the code compiles fine with `-std=c++17`, and gives an error about unknown option for `-std=cpp17`. (I cannot downgrade to 8.2.0.)

Comment: @Chipster: The given error is compile-time, OP does not even make it to link time.

Comment: I tried it with  -std=c++17 and without it , getting the same error